# CORS issue with IE

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have used CORS in my application. In code I mentioned that particular URL(Domain) only need to access my API. Below is the code,

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.Test.com", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);

}
```

As per CORS policy, if I call the above API using the domain **www.Test.com**, then the API response will be shown in my browser(JavaScript client), whereas if I call from another domain(let say www.sample.com) response will not be shown in browser(JavaScript client). This is working fine in the browsers Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

Whereas when I run it from IE browser, this is not working, Even though I call the API from different domain(let say www.sample.com) still the browser render the response. Is there any issue with IE.

Comment: what is `EnableCorsAttribute` class? what is `this.config` and `this.config.EnableCors` ? it appears that you're doing something in the browser to attempt to "bypass" CORS - this is not how cors works ... have you looked in the browser developer tools console to see if there are any errors shown?

Comment: Post the relevant parts of the code that you use to enable CORS

Answer (score 0):

This is because internet explorer 9 and below ignores Access-Control-Allow headers and by default prohibits cross-origin requests for Internet Zone.

as stated in [webdavsystem.com](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests):

> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier ignores Access-Control-Allow headers
>   and by default prohibits cross-origin requests for Internet Zone. To
>   enable cross-origin access go to Tools->Internet Options->Security
>   tab, click on “Custom Level” button. Find the Miscellaneous -> Access
>   data sources across domains setting and select “Enable” option.

Yes, IE is a pain and IE 11 plus Edge are implying to try and make it a little easier but when dealing with IE 9 and below its still going to be as hard as it gets.

Comment: I am facing this issue in IE11